# pandas where function behaving opposite to what I expect

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert NaN's to 0 in a Pandas DataFrame column and the "where" function is behaving the opposite of what I expect.

The following code will create a data frame containing one column with NaN's at index 4,5,6 and 7.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

x = Counter(pd.np.random.choice(24,2000))
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x})
df.loc[4:7,'x'] = pd.np.nan
df
```

I used

```
df.where(df.isnull() == True,0)
```

expecting where the NaN values were to be changed to 0. Instead what happened was everything but the NaN's were changed to 0.

Can anyone explain the logic behind how where works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 df.where(condition,other)
```

where method is an application of the if-then idiom. For each element in the calling DataFrame, if cond is True the element is used; otherwise the corresponding element from the DataFrame other is used.

Simply If condition is satisfied then the dataframe is unchanged else set 0 (any values mentioned in Other Parameter)

A simple change in your code will work fine :

change

```
df.where(df.isnull() == True,0)
```

to

```
df.where(df.notnull() == True,0)
```

or

```
df.where(df.isnull() != True,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to use:

```
df.mask(df.isnull() == True,0)
```

Or

```
df.where(df.isnull() != True,0)
```

Output -- head(10):

```
       x
0   85.0
1   96.0
2   78.0
3   93.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
8  100.0
9   77.0
```

Now, [`df.where(condition,0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas-dataframe-where) states:

> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries
>   are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other.

So it returns the current value when condition is True, otherwise 0.

[`df.mask(condition,0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas-dataframe-mask) does the opposite the docs state:

> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries
>   are from self where cond is False and otherwise are from other.

So it returns the current value when False, otherwise(when True) return 0